# Coefficient of Euclidean Distance

Tags: similarity, euclidean-distance

I have been trying to calculate correlation coefficient (say `r`) and euclidean distance (say `d`) between two random variables `X` and `Y`. It is known that `-1 <= r <= 1`, whereas `d >= 0`. To compare these similarity metrics (mostly for visualization purpose), first I want to calculate a coefficient for `d`, so that it will be between 0 and 1 or between -1 and 1 like `r`. One way to scale `d` is dividing it by its maximum, i.e. `d* = d/max(d)`. However, the maximum `max(d)` is not a global value and when someone uses different data points for `X` and  `Y`, then it is not longer comparable to the first one. Therefore, I'm asking this community to suggest me a better way of scaling the euclidean distance that ranges in `[0, 1]` or `[-1, 1]`.

I appreciate your cooperation in advance.
Alemu

Comment: Are the _ranges_ for `X` and `Y` known ?

Comment: @FrankH. X and Y are standardized random variables, and theoretically they follow standard normal distribution

Comment: I'll have to defer to more-maths people than myself, but to my understanding, this is intractable; normal distribution permits any value `]-inf:inf[` with a non-zero probability (however small), hence the Euclidean distance between two such is not bounded. The _distribution_ of the euclidean distance can be (would be the square of a normal distribution, right ?), but the distance itself, `|x-y|`, cannot be normalized. One also expects `d` to be "anticorrelated" to the correlation coefficient - the "more alike" (`r = 1`) the _smaller_ `d`, and the more-different (`r = -1`) the _larger_ `d` ?